# Is it possible to disable both debugger visualization and ToString() invocation in all the debugger views of VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tostring, debuggervisualizer

My project depends on a 3rd party assembly which defines debugger visualizers for some of its types. Usually this is totally fine, but some types have lazy logic, which becomes eager once the data is observed in the debugger. And when I wish to explore the lazy behavior all this visualizers completely screw it.

I wonder how can I disable both the visualizers and prevent invocation of the ToString() method in all the debugger views in VS2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As for the ToString part of the question, yes, it is.

Go to Options->Debugger-> Uncheck "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls".